# Why explicitly declare classes special functions as "default"

Tags: c++, class, c++11, default

What is the difference between explicitly declaring classes special functions default.

```
class Myclass
{
public:

    Myclass() = default;
    virtual ~Myclass() = default;

    Myclass(MyClass&&) = default;
    Myclass& operator=(MyClass&&) = default;

    Myclass(const MyClass&) = default;
    Myclass& operator=(const MyClass&) = default;
};

MyClass{};
```

What is the difference between this 2 declarations?
Why explicitly specify the default behavioral functions as default??

Comment: the `class MyClass{};` version does not have a virtual destructor.

Comment: `What is the difference between this 2 declarations?` What 2 declarations? You seem to only have included 1 declaration of each special member function.

Comment: 3 reasons: making it explicit to the reader, forcing the compiler to generate them in corner cases where it does not actually generate defaults, making a default private (so that a friend class has access to the default one)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because under certain conditions the compiler might not add the constructors, destructor or operators even though you may want the compiler-generated defaults. Then by using the explicit `default` designator the compiler will do that anyway.

You can find out more in e.g. [this `class` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes).

Comment: also sometimes being explicit can add clarity, you signal that the default generated one was by choice rather than mistake.